# Record error in Scheme/Racket - why do you need to define constructors as mutable?

Tags: scheme, racket

i'm having trouble defining some code in scheme. I am trying to create a record for a node in Scheme/Racket, so far my code looks as follows:

> `(define-record-type node`
>
> > `(make-node v l r)`
> >     `node?` 
> >     `(v tree-value)`
> >     `(l tree-left)`
> >     `(r tree-right))`

However - when I try and execute I get the following error:

> > `define-record-type: expected amutable', immutable',parent', protocol',sealed', opaque',nongenerative', or parent-rtd' clause in: (make-node v l r)`

I understand that you can define field types to be mutable, immutable etc. But I can't see why this needs to be a clause in the constructor - and if so where it should be?

Could someone please explain

1)How to get around this error

2)Why it arises

Comment: This error occurs with `#!r6rs`, but not with `#lang racket` followed by `(require srfi/9)`.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain why? Or how I would get around this without requiring srfi/9? Also if it's #lang scheme can it be solved with (require srfi/9) ?

Comment: In Racket, the idiomatic thing to do is to define records using `struct` with `#lang racket`. Note that `#lang scheme` is a legacy setting that isn't meant for use in new code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not in accordance with [the R6RS standard reference doc](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-7.html), possible definitions are:

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs) (rnrs records syntactic))

(define-record-type node (fields v l r))
(define tree-value (record-accessor node 0))
(define tree-left  (record-accessor node 1))
(define tree-right (record-accessor node 2))
```

or

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs) (rnrs records syntactic))

(define-record-type node 
  (fields 
   (immutable v tree-value)
   (immutable l tree-left)
   (immutable r tree-right)))
```

or

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs) (rnrs records syntactic))

(define-record-type (node make-node node?)
  (fields 
   (immutable v tree-value)
   (immutable l tree-left)
   (immutable r tree-right)))
```

For any of those, you get:

```
(define n (make-node 1 2 3))

(display n) (newline)
=> #(struct:node 1 2 3)

(display (node? n)) (newline)
=> #t

(display (tree-value n)) (newline)
=> 1

(display (tree-left n)) (newline)
=> 2

(display (tree-right n)) (newline)
=> 3
```