# r6rs and define-record-type

Tags: scheme, racket, r6rs

HY everyone,

for class i had to import some libraries.

i got an error, after checking the libraries out, the problem basically boils down to

r6rs that gives this error : **define-record-type: unbound identifier in module in: define-record-type**

in this librarie :

```
#lang r6rs

(library
 (scenario-line)
 (export new say-what says-who say-it)
 (import ;...
  )

 (define-record-type scenario-line
   (new figure text)
   scenario-line?
   (figure says-who)
   (text say-what))

 (define (say-it scenario-line)
   (diagonal-paste (diagonal-paste (says-who scenario-line) 
                                   (new-cloud 15 15)) 
                   (new-text-cloud (say-what scenario-line)))))
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19883861/1193075

Answer (score 1):

You left out your `import` declarations which are the most important part for figuring out unbound identifiers!

The identifier `define-record-type` is exported from the `(rnrs records syntactic)` and thus you'll need to ensure that one of your imports is:

```
(import (rnrs records syntactic))
```

From the R6RS documentation:

> The syntactic layer is provided by the (rnrs records syntactic
>   (6))library. Some details of the specification are explained in terms
>   of the specification of the procedural layer below.
>
> The record-type-defining form define-record-type is a definition and
>   can appear anywhere any other  can appear. ...